HMS Push Kit_Push Service Error for Mobile Browsers
I'm trying to use Huawei Push Kit to push messages to web apps.
An error occurs on Huawei mobile device after registering hms-service worker when I attempt to get token to access Push Kit. The following message is displayed in console for:
Edge:
AbortError: Registration failed - push service error
Mozilla:
Error: messaging: Notifications have been blocked. (messaging/notifications-blocked)
In desktop browsers, token is obtained successfully, web notifications via Push Kit are working.

const messaging = hms.messaging();
messaging.usePublicVapidKey(
    "<my key>");
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('Message received. ', payload);
});

const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("hms-messaging-sw.js", {
    scope: "./hms-cloud-messaging-push-scope"
})
alert('registration')
messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

try {
    const currentToken = await messaging.getToken()
    if (currentToken) {
        console.log('Current token: ', currentToken);
        var paragraph = document.getElementById("root");
        paragraph.innerText = `${currentToken}`;
    } else {
        console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        var paragraph1 = document.getElementById("root");
        paragraph1.innerText = 'No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.';
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err)
    var paragraph2 = document.getElementById("root");
    paragraph2.innerText = `An error occurred while retrieving token - ${err}`;
}```

